# How to Embed Posts from Website or Blog into Facebook Page using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on a module, where requirement is When Admin creates any new post on website or blog, then it should get post on its related Facebook Page also.

I want something like this. But its not working in my case.
Here is code

```
// require Facebook PHP SDK
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
require_once("php-graph-sdk-5.5/src/Facebook/facebook.php");
require_once("php-graph-sdk-5.5/src/Facebook/autoload.php");

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['app_id'] = 'myappud';
$config['app_secret'] = 'myappsecret';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook($config);

// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array(
    "access_token" => "myaccesstoek", // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
    "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook",
    "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
    "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
    "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
    "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
    "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
    $ret = $fb->post('myfburl/feed', $params);
    echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

It giving error as

```
An unknown error occurred
```

For more refer this link => http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php

Help to figure it out where I m making mistake.

**Updated** :

```
    <?php

// Include facebook class (make sure your path is correct)
use Facebook\Facebook; 

require_once ("php-graph-sdk-5.5/src/Facebook/autoload.php");

require_once("php-graph-sdk-5.5/src/Facebook/Facebook.php");

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'app_id'  => 'myappid',
  'app_secret' => 'myappsecret',
  'cookie' => true,
));

//$token is the access token from the URL above
$post = array('access_token' =>'myaccesstoken', 'message' => 'new test post - ' . date('Y-m-d'));

try{
$res = $facebook->post('myfburl/feed',$post);
print_r($res);

} catch (Exception $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: First of all, you can not specify picture, name, caption and description dynamically at the time of sharing any more, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: I remove that but still same error. @CBroe

Comment: What type of access token are you using, and what permissions does it contain?

Comment: profile page access token, profile page permission @CBroe

Comment: And what exactly is “profile page permission” supposed to mean?

Comment: I m stuck there. I m not getting which type of permission should I use. @CBore

Comment: instead of playing around with an article from 2013 (!!!), why not just start reading the official docs? there is detailed information about the permissions you need, about different access tokens, example code, ...

Comment: I tried to use the way you said but still it throwing an unknown error . Updated code also added above. @luschn

Comment: what is "myfburl"? use "me" instead. and make sure the access token is correct.

Comment: actually myfburl means => www.facebook.com/myusername @luschn

Comment: still, you can just use "me", with the user access token

Comment: do you know any example for this?, i m trying but unable to get output @luschn

Comment: did you debug the access token? does it include the correct permissions? for posting to a page you would need a page token with the manage_pages and publish_pages permissions.

Comment: Thanks @luschn. This way worked for me,finally.

Comment: what way? please add an answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: Ya done that. By the way do you know how to achieve same for twitter? @luschn

Comment: did you check out the twitter dev docs?

Comment: Going through this but not getting doc for twitting from website to twitter account. @luschn

Comment: pro tip: google for "twitter api post to twitter" and the first result will be this one: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for posting to a page you would need a page token with the manage_pages and publish_pages permissions

**Example** :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=yourClientId&redirect_uri=yourUri/&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages
```